# Triggering a macro when a cell is updated - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've currently got a set up where a timestamp is triggered once a person enters their name into a specified cell.

What I want to do is have a script trigger when the timestamp updates and copy data into another tab that will be treated as a database.

To put it simply - Timestamp updates in `Sheet1`, this triggers a macro to copy data into `Sheet 3`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Hi, thanks, ... are considered noise](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950);

Comment: Just call your function from the same function that wrote the timestamp